# clone bar repository to normal repository

Tags: git

In this [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-basics#!init),it said central repository should be bare.But I wonder if I clone the bare repository ,such as`git clone https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git`，Will I get a bare repository?How can I get a non-bare repository?

**UPDATE:**
As Nevik Rehnel said,I will get a non-bare repository. But why clone convert bare to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your clone will not be bare, it will be a normal repository with a working copy.

You could easily have tested this by creating a bare repo and then cloning it.

Comment: Why clone convert bare repository to normal?

Comment: because clone will always create a normal (non-bare) repo unless you explicitly tell it to create a bare one. it's just Git's default.